# NSSortDescriptor - has the order changed?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, nssortdescriptor

I have an `NSFetchRequest` that is getting objects from core-data and sorting them using a trivial `NSSortDescriptor`. I use a couple of different ones depending on what the user selects, but they are like this:

```
    NSMutableArray *sortDescriptors = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"ownerName" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor2 = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"petName" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    [sortDescriptors addObject:sortDescriptor1];
    [sortDescriptors addObject:sortDescriptor2];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Everything works as expected on iOS5 and 5.1, however when I test exactly the same code on an iPad running iOS4.2.1 (or the 4.3 simulator) the order of all the first sort descriptor is reversed. In this example, the owners names are ordered Z to A, but the pets are correctly ordered A to Z!

Was there a bug in earlier iOS versions that caused the `ascending` boolean to be the wrong way around? Alternatively, is there something else I may be doing incorrectly?

EDIT: The first key (ownerName) is used as the `NSFetchedResultsController`section. Not sure if this is relevant.

Thanks Craig

Comment: Do you get the right order if you pass `NO` for the `ascending` parameter?

Comment: Yes. I have changed the 'ascending' character on the first SD to NO, and then is mirrors the iOS5 result. The second SD was still set to YES and items within the section were ordered the same way. Weird!

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing.

I have had good results without specifying `caseInsensitiveCompare:`.

Also, strictly speaking `NSFetchRequest` expects an `NSArray` as the `sortDescriptors` argument, not `NSMutableArray`. In all of Apple's sample code it is normally something like

```
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:
   [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor1, sortDescriptor2, nil]];
```

I have had errors like that (using mutable instead of immutable), but often it also just works. Maybe changing that is worth a try.

Comment: Thanks! I tried removing the `caseInsensitiveCompare` but no different. I'll try changing the mutable array into an array, tomorrow to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: I can confirm that this made no difference :(

Comment: Regarding `NSMutableArray` vs. `NSArray`, as `NSMutableArray` is a subclass of `NSArray` then it will be cast automatically when you pass it in so this will not cause you any problems. In a sane OO system every subclass should be able to stand in for its superclass.